# Convert array of strings to an array of objects by splitting the strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a large array of strings formatted like this from AWS S3:

```
1g2LNBuUNMBVppc311kZ / 1Q77N7KbUPOIOXUEJsd.xml
```

I would like to convert this to an array of objects with folder names (the first part of the string until the /) and an array of files for each object. The file name is the part of the string after the slash. Example

```
[ { FolderName: '1g2LNBuUNMBVppc311kZ', Files: [123.xml, aba.xml] }, {} ]
```

any suggestions as to how I could do this.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow, always try something before coming here, and show an effort you made in trying to answer your own question (posting code that didn't work is always a good start). Otherwise you'll probably get downvoted because you should help people help you and many others who might be facing the same problem in the future (or in the past). :)

Comment: How to you get 2 files in output array from the input shown? How are you getting this array of strings? Sounds like you should be mapping it at source. What is shown is not n rray at ll either

Comment: this array is the result of querying s3. All the characters before the slash is the folder name. Each folder has a minimum of 20 files so I was trying to break it up to make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var array = [
  "1g2LNBuUNMBVppc311kZ / 1Q77N7KbUPOIOXUEJsd.xml",
  "1g2LNBuUNMBVppc311kZ / foo.xml",
  "foo / bar.xml"
];
var output = array.reduce(function(array, field) {
  var found = null;
  var fields = field.split(/\s*\/\s*/);
  // search for folder
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if (array[i].folderName == fields[0]) {
      found = array[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  if (found) {
    // found folder push to files
    found.files.push(fields[1]);
  } else {
    // new folder
    array.push({folderName: fields[0], files: [fields[1]]});
  }
  return array;
}, []);
alert(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: I'm nit picking but your using `Array.reduce()` (functional style) but inside you branch the complexity several times with if/else and for loops. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the array to an object. First workout a helper function for the splitting logic:

```
// convert String "path / file" into ["path", "file"]
function splitPath(string) {
  var parts = string.split('/');
  return [parts[0].trim(), parts.slice(1).join('/').trim()];
}
```

Then use `reduce()` to convert to an object:

```
function toObject(data) {
  return data.reduce(function(memo, entry) {
    var parts = splitPath(entry);
    var folder = memo[parts[0]] || [];
    folder.push(parts[1]);
    memo[parts[0]] = folder;
    return memo;
  }, {});
}
```

And since you asked for an array of objects heres how to convert it:

```
function toArrayOfObjects(folders) {
  Object.keys(folders).map(function(folderName) {
    return {
      FolderName: folderName,
      Files: folders[folderName]
    };
  });
}
```